# Does purchasing tickets for the Empire State Building in advance allow me to skip the queues?

Tags: tickets, planning, tips-and-tricks, sightseeing, new-york-city

I went to the Empire State Building today and it was obviously very busy. The queue to get in was 1h30m long so I decided to come back later, and maybe even book tickets in advance. Now, I see that various ticketing options are available so I'd like some elucidations.

How many queues are there to go in the Empire State Building? Does purchasing tickets in advance allow me to skip the queues? If so which tickets and which queues? How does one jump the queues? Is there a separate entrance for ticket holders?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**How many queues are there to go in the Empire State Building?** A lot and almost non-stop

**Does purchasing tickets in advance allow me to skip the queues?** No, it doesn't. You gotta buy a specific ticket called *VIP Express Pass*.

**If so which tickets and which queues?** VIP Express Ticket

**How does one jump the queues? Is there a separate entrance for ticket holders?** I don't remember, but I think there is a separate entrance. You can always ask ticket agents outside of the building.
P.S.: There is a separate entrance and line for express VIP ticket holders.

Comment: +1 There *is* a separate entrance and line for express VIP ticket holders. Add this to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you buy the VIP Express Pass beforehand.

However, you may still be 'delayed' at the elevator, particularly when coming down.

Comment: Yes what? :) What do I do once i buy the VIP express pass? How do I jump the queue? This morning all I could see was a single giant line of visitors. And the esp website is less than useless on the topic.

Comment: Once you arrive, you can look for Express Pass entrances.  There will be ESB representatives handling the crowds that can direct you to do the proper location.  Queue locations can change so unfortunately, this is something you will have to locate on arrival.

Comment: add all this information to your answer. Be pedagogical. :)